# Change values of matrix where row names equal column names

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to change the values of a matrix so that, for each element where the row name equals the column name, the resulting matrix will have a value of one.

```
> z<-matrix(0, nrow=10, ncol=8)
> colnames(z)<-letters[1:8]
> rownames(z)<-c("f", "c", "a", "f", "a", "b", "f", "b", "h", "c")
> z
  a b c d e f g h
f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
c 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
a 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
a 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
b 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
b 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
c 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

z should be:

```
  a b c d e f g h
f 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
c 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
a 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
f 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
a 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
b 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
f 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
b 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
c 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

I tried:

```
> z[unique(rownames(z)), unique(rownames(z))]<-1
> z
  a b c d e f g h
f 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
c 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
a 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
a 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
b 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
b 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
h 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
c 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and:

```
> z["a", "a"]<-1
> z
  a b c d e f g h
f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
c 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
a 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
a 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
b 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
b 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
c 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

but that only changed the first 'a' in the 'a' column.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also do this with base R using `outer`.

```
z[outer(rownames(z), colnames(z), "==")] <- 1
z
  a b c d e f g h
f 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
c 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
a 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
f 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
a 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
b 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
f 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
b 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
c 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `row/column` indexing to change the elements to 1

```
z[cbind(1:nrow(z), match( rownames(z), colnames(z)))] <- 1
z
#  a b c d e f g h
#f 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
#c 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
#a 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#f 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
#a 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#b 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
#f 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
#b 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
#h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
#c 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

Or another option is (should be slower for big datasets)

```
`dimnames<-`(+(sapply(colnames(z), `==`, rownames(z))), dimnames(z))
#  a b c d e f g h
#f 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
#c 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
#a 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#f 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
#a 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#b 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
#f 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
#b 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
#h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
#c 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

NOTE: BTW, both the solutions are `base R` only solutions and not came from some external packages.

#### Benchmarks

```
z1 <- matrix(0, 5000, 5000)
colnames(z1) <- 1:5000
set.seed(24)
row.names(z1) <- sample(1:5000, 5000, replace=TRUE)
z2 <- z1
z3 <- z1
z4 <- z1
system.time(z1[cbind(1:nrow(z1), match( rownames(z1), colnames(z1)))] <- 1)
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.03    0.08    0.11 
system.time(z2[outer(rownames(z2), colnames(z2), "==")] <- 1)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.67    0.16    0.83 
identical(z1, z2)
#[1] TRUE

system.time( `dimnames<-`(+(sapply(colnames(z3), `==`, rownames(z3))), dimnames(z3)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  31.70    0.39   32.28 

system.time(z3[vapply(colnames(z3), function(x) x== rownames(z3), 
         logical(nrow(z3)))] <- 1)
#  user  system elapsed 
#   0.22    0.00    0.21
```

Testing with @Procrastinatus Maximus modification

```
system.time(z4[sapply(colnames(z4), `==`, rownames(z4))] <- 1)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  28.42    0.36   28.85
```

By testing it on a 10000 x 10000 matrix, the timings are

```
system.time(z1[cbind(1:nrow(z1), match( rownames(z1), colnames(z1)))] <- 1)
#   user  system elapsed 
#    0.12    0.32    0.44 
system.time(z2[outer(rownames(z2), colnames(z2), "==")] <- 1)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.72    0.86    3.58
```

and on 20000 X 20000 matrix

```
system.time(z1[cbind(1:nrow(z1), match( rownames(z1), colnames(z1)))] <- 1)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.95    1.00    1.95 
system.time(z2[outer(rownames(z2), colnames(z2), "==")] <- 1)
#    user  system elapsed 
#   15.47    5.87   21.39
```

Comment: What should `nomatch` be?

Comment: @MichaelChirico  It can be 0

Comment: you got and still have an upvote from me. I was adding the comment for completeness/my own edification

Answer (score 3):

Another option is (which is a modification of @akrun's 2nd option):

```
z[sapply(colnames(z), `==`, rownames(z))] <- 1
```

which also gives the correct answer:

```
> z
  a b c d e f g h
f 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
c 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
a 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
f 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
a 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
b 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
f 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
b 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
c 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

The difference with @akrun's 'dimnames' solution is that in the above approach only the necessary spots are converted to `1` which is an advantage when the original matrix doesn't just contain zero's. This is also achieved by the 'outer'-option from @lmo and the 'cbind'-option of @akrun.