# Update records of dataframe where row names equal to column names

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, pivot-table

Hello I have a large dataframe where I have need to update or fill in the missing values. The condition is that the correct value should be in respect to row name matching to a column name. For example:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  
  ID = c("x", "y", "z"), 
  x = c("1", "0.45", "0.47"),
  y = c("0.45", "1", "0.65"),
  z = c("XXXX", "XXXX", "1")
)

  ID    x    y    z
1  x    1 0.45 XXXX
2  y 0.45    1 XXXX
3  z 0.47 0.65    1
```

Above, the correct values for `xxxx` should be 0.47 and 0.65, respectively. Because x col z row has 0.47. Then y col z row is 0.65.The dataframe then looks like this:

```r
  ID    x    y    z
1  x    1 0.45 0.47
2  y 0.45    1 0.65
3  z 0.47 0.65    1
```

This way all the elements row wise or column wise would correspond to matching rowname and column name.

I have looked into these posts but I couldn't use them to advance my solutions:

1. [Match Column to Column Names, add value to row/column of Matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72874065/match-column-to-column-names-add-value-to-row-column-of-matches)
2. [data frame set value based on matching specific row name to column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977760/data-frame-set-value-based-on-matching-specific-row-name-to-column-name)
3. [Change values of matrix where row names equal column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367765/change-values-of-matrix-where-row-names-equal-column-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do this in `base R`

```
i1 <- upper.tri(df[-1])
i2 <- lower.tri(df[-1])
 df[-1][i1] <- df[-1][i2]
```

-output

```
> df
  ID    x    y    z
1  x    1 0.45 0.47
2  y 0.45    1 0.65
3  z 0.47 0.65    1
```

---

Or use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df[-1][upper.tri(df[-1])] <- coalesce(na_if(df[-1][upper.tri(df[-1])], 
        "XXXX"), df[-1][lower.tri(df[-1])])
```

---

Or may convert to 'long' format and then reshape back to wide format after `fill`ing

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(),  ~  na_if(.x, "XXXX"))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>%
  group_by(ID2 = str_c(pmin(ID, name), pmax(ID, name))) %>% 
  fill(value, .direction = "downup") %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-ID2) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  ID    x     y     z    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 x     1     0.45  0.47 
2 y     0.45  1     0.65 
3 z     0.47  0.65  1
```

Comment: Hi akrun! (hope you're doing well). I need to preserve the Z column. This is taking away the z column sadly. I had a similar solution before but in my large dataframe it will cause issues because I am using some columns later on.

Comment: Thank you, with my large dataframe I get `Error:
! Subscript upper.tri(rf[-1]) is a matrix, the data coalesce(...) must have size 1.
Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.` After casting the dataframe as matrix I get `Error in coalesce():
! Can't recycle ..1 (size 0) to match ..2 (size 11128).
Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: @AOE_player Can yyou try the update

Comment: Yes the new answer works! Thank you Akrun :)

Comment: @AOE_player I edited your edit as you were using `mutate_all` which is deprecated in favor of `across`

Comment: Sounds good, thank you Akrun! Sorry I am using old R version that's why used mutate_all.

Answer (score 1):

For your provided data frame we could like this:
I am not sure if it will work for your entire dataset:

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

t(df) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  row_to_names(row_number = 1) %>% 
  filter(row_number() <= n()-1) %>% 
  bind_rows(df %>% 
              slice(n())) %>% 
  mutate(ID = colnames(df[-1]))
```

```
  x     y     z     ID   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1     0.45  0.47  x    
2 0.45  1     0.65  y    
3 0.47  0.65  1     z
```

Comment: Unfortunately, The results are not correct when I tested with my original dataframe. All the values are being updated, not just `xxxxxx` Akrun's answer above (the dplyr one) works and does what I was trying to do. Thank you very much for your help and time.